# entropy in information theory vs thermodynamic?

Tags: entropy, information

We know from information theory that the entropy of a deterministic function of a random variable $X$ is less than or equal to the entropy of $X$.

[image: Block diagram depicting a function of a random variable and its output]

Does this phenomenon violate the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: What the equation intuitively tells us is that you cannot add entropy via a deterministic function (but you can surely take it away, for example by the trivial mapping g(x) = 1). Could you clarify in the question why you think this might break the second law?

Comment: second law say that the entropy of an isolated system never decrease . if we consider the system above as an isolated system, it goes from one equilibrium state to another and entropy decrease! thank you

Comment: To enact g(X) you have to do something, put energy in. You expressions describe that there is a change in a system, and that it is deterministic, but they don't say how it is enacted. (or describe physically what the system is).

If you try to do this in a closed system (you cannot put energy in) then it cannot be the case that g(X) is a deterministic function. You can have a local increase in order, but the energy source will add a greater amount of disorder, and that will not be deterministic.